# How to handle errors from web service

Tags: java, spring, rest, error-handling

Sorry I am new to Spring and Java and this may be covered lots of times but I wanted to get some advice.

I'm creating a Spring web application which needs to retrieve user data from an existing REST based XML web service. I am going to create a domain object, service and DAO which uses the Spring REST template to invoke the web service.

In the DAO I was going to create a method like this:

```
public User getUser(String userId)
```

If there is a problem (for example if the user account is locked or been deleted), the web service returns a 200 response and puts an error code in the XML response. These errors should be displayed in the application and I will need to be able to identify the error so I can show custom error message to the user. What is the recommended way to handle these error, should I:

1. Define different exceptions (runtime) for each of the error response codes and add these to the method signature
2. Use a single exception (e.g. UserException) and use different messages.
3. Do something else

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use different exception for each error type by extending Extension. if you have many different ones, try to group them using class inheritance. An example would make it simpler. Suppose you have these 2 kinds of errors, account deleted and account locked, you would do :

```
class AccountException
    extends Exception {
}
```

then you extend Account extension for all the errors involving account problems, eg:

```
class AccountLockedException
    extends AccountException {
}
```

and

```
class AccountDeletedException
    extends AccountException {
}
```

etc... This way you make it crystal clear and don't have to look through all your exceptions. Not sure I'm clear enough, It's my first answer here. GL!

Answer (score 1):

I would create a single Exception class for a category. For instance, for all user related exceptions, you can create something like below:
This way, it will be  clean to catch one exception and verify the error code to find what caused the exception.

```
public class MyException extends Exception{
        public static final int ERR_USER_NOT_FOUND  = 101;
        public static final int ERR_DB_ACCESS_ERR = 500;

        private int errorCode;
        public MyException(int errCode){
            this.errorCode = errCode;
        }

        public int getErrorCode() {
            return errorCode;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll try both these out. Just wanted to check is there any other way of doing this without using Java exceptions?